# Firefox: first CORS Request is blocked, second works

Tags: javascript, php, firefox, xmlhttprequest, cors

An OpenLayers-Script on server A makes a CORS request with basic auth to Server B  to get an image (A & B are my servers).
It works in Chrome & Safari. Firefox blocks the request. In network tab I can resend the request, second request is not blocked and gets the image.

I checked security certificates and disabled all Firefox extensions, first call ist still blocked.

My Javascript for the request:

```
var client = new XMLHttpRequest();
client.open('GET', src, true, username, password); 
client.withCredentials = true;
client.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + btoa(username + ':' + password));
client.responseType = 'blob';
client.addEventListener('loadend', function(evt) {
    var data = this.response;
    if (data !== undefined && data !== null) {
        image.getImage().src = URL.createObjectURL(data);
    }
```

Headers send by Server B:

```
function print_headers($content_type, $referer) {
       header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: " . $referer); // https://serverA.com
       header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true");
       header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS");
       header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: access-control-allow-headers, access-control-allow-methods, access-control-allow-origin, authorization, content-type, accept, origin, X-Auth-Token");
       header('WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="my service"');
       header($content_type); // Content-Type: image/png
   }
```

Response to option request:

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'OPTIONS') {
    $this->_exit(200);
}   

function _exit($code) {
    $this->print_headers('Content-Type: text/xml', $this->referer);
    http_response_code($code);
    exit(0);       
}
```

Firefox network tab after second request:
[image: Firefox network tab after second request]

Comment: I don't see your OPTION request in your network tab. I believe firefox uses a options preflight request to check the CORS settings. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS

Comment: option request gets response code 200

Comment: Did you check the option request's headers? They should be cors/accept headers

Comment: What does the console say?

Comment: `header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: " . $referer); // https://serverA.com` – are you sure the referrer is always going to be just that? If that was not just protocol plus host name plus maybe port, but included a path or something as well, that would be an invalid value for that header to begin with.

Comment: file path is stripped away from referer before sending headers